# Macos SSHFS produce broken mountpoint

Tags: macos, sshfs

[broken mount point, as it seens in mc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7Ijj.png)
I'm trying to mount my work servers to local folder. 
"sudo sshfs webuser@rgslb.com:/var/www/webuser/data/www /Volumes/rgslb.com"

It asks me password and silently proceed. But as result I have broken file, in mc it looks like ?rgslb.com, but "ls -l" says that there no this file in /Volumes. And when I unmounted it this mount point directory disappear. 
Have any one has same situation? Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

I got simple solution, do sshfs... without `sudo`, to `~/rgslb.com`. And it works.